# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createContext' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, package.json

Im trying to build my application using **npm run build** .

I get the error as 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'createContext' of undefined` .

I have made the following changes after checking for a solution

I tried upgrading the **react and react dom to ^16.4** . 
Still getting the same error .

I have defined in my component as react.default.createContext() 
I did a console in my component and found react.default is undefined .

And it is in this part the error is occurring .

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const react_1 = require("react");
const initStore = {
    i18n: {},
    query: {}
};
exports.AppContext = react_1.default.createContext(initStore);
exports.withAppContext = (Children) => {
    return class App extends react_1.default.Component {
        static async getInitialProps(ctx = {}) {
            if (Children.hasOwnProperty('getInitialProps')) {
                const context = Object.assign(ctx, {});
                const childProps = (await Children.getInitialProps(context)) || {};
                return Object.assign(childProps, {});
            }
            else {
                return {};
            }
        }
        render() {
            return <exports.AppContext.Consumer>{app => <Child {...this.props} app={app}/>}</exports.AppContext.Consumer>;
        }
    };
};
```

I have shared my package.json file below

```
{
  "name": "next-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "child_process": false,
    "fork": false
  },
  "fork": false,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.3",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
    "apollo-link-retry": "^2.2.15",
    "apollo-link-timeout": "^1.4.0",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.19",
    "apollo-utilities": "^1.3.3",
    "aws-xray-sdk-core": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.4.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "ctrip-apollo": "^4.4.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-hooks-memcache": "^1.3.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery-param": "^1.0.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "koa": "^2.11.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^8.0.6",
    "memcached": "^2.2.2",
    "next": "^9.0.1",
    "next-config": "^0.1.0",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "next-server": "^9.0.5",
    "polished": "^3.4.4",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-dnd": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
    "react-progressive-image": "^0.6.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-tools": "^1.7.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.21",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "ycb": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

Is it some sort of version issue ? im using Nextjs as framework over react also

Comment: I guess hooks were introduced in **16.8**.

Comment: `react.default.createContenxt()` seems a typo rather i suggest you to [go here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: @Jai I have updated my package.json react 
to 16.8 still im getting the same error . 
I have used . 
```exports.WebContext = react_1.default.createContext(store) ```
thanks

Comment: @Jai Event after upgrading to correct version , im still getting the issue . What could be the ideal solution for this .

Comment: Isn't it should be `react_1.createContext` instead of `react_1.default.createContext`?